# How to repeat a XAML in WPF

Tags: wpf

How to repeat a UI in WPF. I mean if I have dynamic records, and I want to display a UI block with labels and textboxes and other controls for each record how do I do that?

All my data on the window is dynamic, nothing is static,

```
 Record 1 in database:        test1 test11 
                         d1     t1   t11
                         r1     m1   m11

 Record 2 in database:        test2  test22 test222
                         d2     t2     t22    t222
                         r2     m2     m22    m222
                         k2     k2     k22    k222
```

I have a big object TEST with all this values eg, test1, test11, d1, r1, t1, t11, m1, m11, etc.
 All the rows and columns are dynamic. How will I create an UI for the above requirement.
I am sorry if this is not clear and is too confusing to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty vague, so the answers will follow suit.

Generically, you use an `ItemsControl` (or one if its inheritors) and set its `ItemsSource` property to the collection of records.
You define a `DataTemplate` with everything needed to display a single record.
You assign that `DataTemplate` as the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @developer. Jay is right on the money but you may need to 'play' with what he's said a bit before it really makes sense to you. [Dr WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/itemscontrol/) has the best free tutorial I have seen for something like this. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use an ItemsControl add the the controls to the ItemsControl's ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

A Data template helps us to display a collection of data in customized format or base on business requirement.  In simpler terms, a DataTemplate provides you great flexibility to define the presentation of your data on the user interface.